# Can I remove the undoManager of UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, nsundomanager

I was wondering if I can remove the undoManager of UISearchbar, because I don't plan to make use of it. Or is there any way for me to disable or hide it?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this?